# How to use ConstraintLayout to center in parent a ImageView on the side of two vertical TextViews

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need a layout where a ImageView is on the right of 2 vertical TextViews like this:

[image]

I want both ImageView and TextViews to be centred in the parent layout, although the TextViews should be together.

The xml layout code that I have is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="some text here that can be more than text view 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/text_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_view" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_400"
        android:text="some here"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_1"  />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I only know how to constraint the ImageView with one of the TextView.
When the text from text_view_1 is too big it will fell out of the screen. If I put `layout_constrainedWidth` in `text_view_1` it will be constrained to `text_view_2`'s width.

How can I set the constrains in this case so that each TextView can increase its size until reaches the available space and fold to a second line?

I have accomplished the desired behaviour by putting the TextViews in a LinearLayout but I would like to know how to avoid an extra layout.

Edit:

some more images of what I want:

[image]

[image]

I would like to avoid this:

[image]

Comment: share the real design what you want to create

Comment: I added a few more images

Comment: When you say centered. You want equal space on the left of the image and the right of text_view_1 or text_view_2 or both text_view_1 and text_view_2

Comment: equal spacing on the left of the image and on the right of the most right between text_view_1 and text_view_2

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` for the *TextViews*.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Short text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/text_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="Text that spans multiple lines."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

If you don't like the extra space at the end of the *TextViews*, you can turn on justification with `android:justificationMode="inter_word"` for Android 8.0+.

Comment: I did try layout_constrainedWidth but only works well when text_view_2 text is bigger than text_view_1, if "text that spans multiple lines" is on text_view_1 and text_view_2 only has "short text" the image_view does not adjust to the left when text_view_1 gets bigger.

Comment: I see your point. I don't think there is a way to do what you want without a) coding it, or, b) doing something so convoluted that it would be hard to understand or modify. I would just make use of a nested _ViewGroup_.